# Php list all category from table

Tags: php

**Table structure -> Table**

```
id   category   year
--------------------    
1    logo      2001
2    web       2002
3    mobile    2003
```

Is it possible list all category from "flat" table (category - no id) and select only specific category?

**Output**

```
   * logo
   * web
   * mobile

/public/products.php?category=
```

**Code**

```
<?php $photo = new Product(); ?>    

  <ul class="category">
  <?php foreach(Product::CATEGORIES as $category) { ?>
     <li class="<?php if($photo->category == $category) { echo 'selected'; } ?>">
         <a href="<?php echo url_for('products.php?category=' . h(u($photo->category))); ?>">
         <?php echo $category; ?>
         </a>
     </li>
  <?php } // ?>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I am not sure but I think php has where clause choice for selecting specific things! Like WHERE category = 2 :)

Comment: @Dlk I know that  "WHERE id='" .  $id . "'"; in this case it is "id":)

Comment: thanks a lot ! very usefull comment :)